# Android SDK 23.02 on Ubuntu 12.04 produces "No such file or directory" error for all tools

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, android-build

I downloaded the Android SDK r23.02 and extracted it to the directory /home/aleph/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux. I am getting an error "No such file or directory" whenever I try to execute any tool executable provided.

```
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$ uname -a
Linux Xanadu 3.11.0-26-generic #45~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:35 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$ pwd
/home/aleph/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$ build-tools/21.1.0/aapt
bash: build-tools/21.1.0/aapt: No such file or directory
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$ ls -l build-tools/21.1.0/aapt 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 aleph aleph 1248409 Nov  5 15:43 build-tools/21.1.0/aapt
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$ platform-tools/adb 
bash: platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$ ls -l platform-tools/adb
-rwxrwxr-x 1 aleph aleph 1318951 Nov  5 15:43 platform-tools/adb
aleph@Xanadu:~/SoftwareDevelopment/android-sdk-linux$
```

I also tried this with the Eclipse ADT bundle, and I'm getting the same issue. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 1):

install support lib for android

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 1):

ia32-libs is depricated (Ubuntu 14+).
use

`sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386`

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0`

Answer (score 0):

go to your SDk's directory in terminal with cd command and execute this

```
chmod -R +x .
```

make sure that eclipse process have permissions to access the files under SDK dir.